# PHP empty array deceleration throwing error

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the third party provided PHP binary for implementing chat server.
In that PHP binary, most of the PHP classes contain below code

```
$list = $list[0];
```

Just above the line `$list=$list[0]` there is one more line `$db = Db::getInstance();` in my PHP class. I am not sure might be this getInstance code is trying to populate list array.

Whenever API is called the PHP classes its throwing below error

```
Undefined variable: list in /var/www/HeXXX/XXXX/city.php on line 53
```

I am new to PHP and not able to find the solution. Might be its duplicate question but I have already searched in StackOverflow and didn't get the similar post.

Full code :

```
public static function all() {
           // $list = [0];
            $db = Db::getInstance();
               $list = $list[0];
            $req = $db->query('SELECT * FROM users');
            // we create a list of Post objects from the database results
           foreach($req->fetchAll() as $user) {
              $list[] = new User($user['userid'], $user['firstName'], $user['lastName'], $user['email'], $user['password'], $user['status'], $user['regTime'], $user['username'], $user['avata        r'], $user['gender'], $user['dob'], $user['vCode'], $user['city_id'], $user['country'], $user['mobile'], $user['dating_status'], $user['interest_in'], $user['about_me'],$user['request_        limit']);
           }

           return $list;
         }
```

Comment: Could you provide further information on the error?

Comment: @jonystorm I just updated my post with more info about error, I am always getting error Undefined variable: list, It looks like my apache version is not compatible but I am not sure please help me.

Comment: If you've not defined `$list` before that point..well...its undefined.

Comment: It's impossible to say what you expect - there is no variable named `$list` in the example you've provided. You'll need to provide more context. This is not an apache compability issue.

Comment: Just above the line `$list=$list[0] ` there is one more line `$db = Db::getInstance();` I am not sure might be this getInstance code is trying to populate list array.

Comment: It won't introduce an `$list` value into the scope by itself, so the reason for the error is that the variable `$list` is undefined - meaning that it never was initialized. Unless you set the variable to a value, you'll get a notice when you try to access it. Initialize it properly first, and it will behave as you expect.

Comment: @MatsLindh I updated my post with full code. Problem is that its third party library and I should not temper any php file.

Comment: Well - it's trying to access `$list` before it has been set - that will be a notice regardless of it being third party or not. You (or the library author) probably wanted `$list = array();` to initialize the `$list` variable to an empty array first.

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks , I am not sure why the code was written in that way. I am proceeding to change the code according to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notice is telling you that something is accessing the `$list` variable before it has been set. This is caused by `$list[0]` having to be evaluated to give `$list` a value.

You (or the library author) probably wanted $list = array(); to initialize the `$list` variable to an empty array first.

Comment: Just adding in my two cents, `$list = [];` also works or you can keep it out entirely as it is not needed since you're not getting values, just appending them `$list[] = 'value';` That is.. unless you don't have any users in the table because then it returns null instead of an empty array.

Comment: @Xorifelse Yup - but that's >=PHP5.4, so we'll go with what's safe :-) And because of the possibility that there's no users, initializing is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that line with:

```
if (!empty($list[0])){
    $list = $list[0];
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse Javascript and PHP. There is no such thing as `typeof` as an operator or `undefined` in PHP (the corresponding function and value would be gettype and null).

Comment: @jonystorm actually this is third party library and I should not suppose to temper any file. However I observed that before this array code there is one my line as `$db = Db::getInstance();` and might be this is trying to update list array.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.